# Vector Addition and Subtraction - interpretation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

If we have two vectors $a$ and $b$, both in $\Bbb R^n$, is it correct to think of

1. $a-b$ as how similar the two vectors are?
2. $a + b$ as moving the vector $a$ in the direction of vector $b$?

Comment: A start: does it make sense to you in $\mathbb{R}^1$?

Comment: I suggest you to draw some examples in say $\mathbb{R}^2$ to get the feeling.

Comment: GFauxPas, the subtraction part does I suppose as a difference between two numbers could be thought of I guess of how far apart they are in magnitude. The addition part doesn't as much, but if I plot vectors in 2-D it does. I ask this question because I was seeing a Coursera course where they suggested adding a vector b to a vector a moves a in the direction of a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, but this has to do with $R^n$ being a normed space rather than its algebraic properties. What this means is that in an abstract vector space you can't say what does it mean for a vector to be "small" unless you have a norm, or something similar.
2. Yes.

Comment: Is subtraction of the two vectors a useful way to describe how similar they are? Or is the cosine a much better way (comment above)?

Comment: @B_Miner If you're working with the usual norm of $R^n$, then the norm of $a-b$ is  $$\|a-b\|^2 = (a_1-b_1)^2+\cdots+(a_n-b_n)^2,$$ and this certainly measures how similar the two vectors are. I don't understand the cosine part, but cosine would only have to do with the angle between the vectors, which isn't enough to determine if they are similar or not.

Comment: OK so subtraction of the vectors is not enough, we need to look at the norm of a-b.

Comment: By cosine I meant the dot product as one of the other answers mentioned.

Comment: @B_Miner Taking the norm is the mathematical way of using a ruler, so yes. It's so easy to do it when you work with $R^n$ that we do it without paying attention, but it's always there, e.g., the vector $(10^{-5},0,0)$ is small because its norm is small!

Comment: @B_Miner It all depends on what one means by "similar," since that's not an inherently rigorous term.  I was using [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity), which is of use in machine learning.  The norm of the difference of two vectors is another way of denoting similarity, but it all depends on *how you define* similarity.

Comment: @B_Miner Since we're explaining our ideas about what "similar" entails, I'll weigh in.  The reason I didn't consider $a-b$ or $\|a-b\|$ to be enough to tell how similar two vectors are is because I think you also need some idea of the scale of the vectors $a$ and $b$.  So maybe if $\dfrac {\|a-b\|}{\|a\|}$ and $\dfrac {\|a-b\|}{b}$ are both much less than $1$, then I'd say the two vectors $a$ and $b$ are very similar.  But then, it's still a pretty vague concept.

Answer (score 3):

We can think of vector addition, $\vec a + \vec b$, as describing the point at the end of $\vec b$ if $\vec b$ started at the tip of $\vec a$.  In the picture below, the red vector is $\color{red}{\vec{a}}$, the blue vector is $\color{blue}{\vec b}$, and the yellow vector is $\vec a + \vec b$:

[image: Vector Addition]

For vector subtraction, it is best to think of it with regards to addition.  First, realize that $-\vec a$ is just $\vec a$ reflected about the origin.  Then, treat $\vec{a} - \vec{b}$ as $\vec{a} + (-\vec{b})$ and visualize it as with addition.

If you're looking for a measure of vector similarity, we typically use the *inner product* or *dot product*: $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}$.  This makes since, because we'd like to think of "similarity" as a scalar quantity, rather than a whole vector.  If you've learned the relationship between the dot product and cosine, this makes a bit more sense:

$$\vec a \cdot \vec b = \|\vec a\|\|\vec b\|\cos\theta$$
...where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors, as in the image below:
[image: two vectors with an angle between them]

So, vectors that point in the same direction are "similar," while vectors that point in opposite directions are "dissimilar."  Normalization is helpful here, because then $+1$ means "identical vectors," and $-1$ means "reflected vectors."  A value of $0$ means perpendicular.

Answer (score 3):

When I want to draw a representation of vector addition, $v+w$, and subtraction, $v-w$, I just remember that they are the diagonals of the parallelogram with sides $v$ and $w$:

[image]

Here's a way to visualize vector addition physically.  Consider a bird (or airplane) flying on a windy day.  If vector $v$ represents the velocity of the bird without the wind and $w$ represents the velocity of the wind, then $v+w$ is the actual velocity of the bird.  So just picture this: on a day with strong wind, the direction a bird is pointing will not necessarily be the direction its actually flying.

For vector subtraction, just think about displacements.  If you're at the head-end of vector $w$ and you move to the head-end of vector $v$, then the vector you move along is $v-w$.

---

I'm not sure how to quantify the similarity of two vectors, but for instance, you can quantify how parallel/perpendicular they are.

The closer to parallel that two vectors are, the closer to $\|v\|\|w\|$ that the dot product of $v$ and $w$ is.

The closer to perpendicular that two vectors are, the closer to $\|v\|\|w\|$ that the magnitude of the cross product of $v$ and $w$ is.

Thinking of vector addition as moving one vector in the direction of another is an interesting way to think about it.  And it works in $\Bbb R^n$, so if you want to think of it that way, there's no harm.  In fact, this idea of moving one vector along another is anticipating something you'll learn later called "parallel transport" -- though this concept really doesn't have much to do with vector addition in general.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTR0dfsFicY) of a bird in a strong wind shows you what happens when you add two vectors equal in magnitude but opposite in direction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Euclidean space generalizes naturally to n dimensions.

Firstly, Euclidean space admits the L-2 metric, so when computing differences and additions, how "similar" they are or "how much you moved" depends on the distances of them you compute using the metric.

Euclidean metric gives a natural measure of "distance" as we're used to in 1, 2, 3 dimensional space. On the other hand if you switch to a different metric space the meaning is lost. So, metric matters.

Secondly, you can see lower dimensional objects as projections of them sitting in higher dimension.

Imagine a 3D cube, originally sitting in 5 dimensional space with axes v,w,x,y,z; but its length, width and height happen to coincide with axes x,y,z, so we can view the cube naturally in our natural frame of reference.